# Почему не запускает окно в Python Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Смтрю урок по Kivy и в PyCharm реализовать вызов окна с кнопкой с текстом....но вместо этого выводится в консоли красным цветом:

```
[INFO ] [Logger ] Record log in C:\Users\[тип имя компа]\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-08-01_0.txt
[INFO ] [Kivy ] v1.10.1
[INFO ] [Python ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO ] [Factory ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO ] [Image ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO ] [Text ] Provider: sdl2
```

Сам код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text = "Это моя первая кнопка")

if __name__ == "__test__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Не понимаю в чем проблема, в консоле проверил на наличии Python и Kivy подключил в PyCharm в чем проблема?

Comment: Окно с кнопкой не показалось?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо    `if __name__ == "__test__":` используйте `if __name__ == "__main__":`.